# Dynamic ranges in Excel

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula

I have the cells `$A$4:$J$13` defined as `myRange`.  I would like to be able to put the sum of the values in column `H` within `myRange` (i.e. `$H$4:$$13`) in cell `$H$3`.  I know that `=SUM(OFFSET(myRange,0,7,10,1))` will do the trick until…. The user inserts a row(s) or column(s) within `myRange`.  The 7 columns over and 10 rows deep are not updated.  Is there a way to dynamically specify the boundaries of the cells I wish to sum?

Comment: What would you like to happen if, for example, the user inserts a new column before column H? What value do you want to see in H3 in that case?

Comment: The Intersection operaror - a space - will handle row insertions, e.g., `=SUM(myRange H:H)`. Assuming you want the formula to adjust left or right when inserting columns, this will also work for that. For example, after inserting a column the formula will now be `=SUM(myRange I:I)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following in H3,

```
=SUM(INDEX(myRange, 0, 8))
'since you are originating the named range in column A and want the formula in H3 then the
' following will also do and should adjust for inserted columns and rows within myRange.
=SUM(INDEX(myRange, 0, COLUMN()))
=SUM(INDEX(myRange, 0, COLUMN(H:H)))
```

Avoid volatile¹ functions whenever possible.

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>